# In-browser filesystem

Tags: software-development, web-browser, library, javascript

Looking for a solid filesystem implementation that works with Safari and Chrome.

My ideal API looks like [shelljs](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs):

```
// write
'hello world'.to('greeting.txt');

// read
var str = cat('greeting.txt');
```

I should clarify that I'm looking for a place to put data and treat it like files, but it doesn't have to actually write to files on disk.

I'm expecting a fully cross browser solution will likely need to use indexeddb and websql, except on Chrome. localStorage is not desired because it can only hold small amounts of data.

Safari support is a must, so need something that can work with websql, perhaps through the [indexeddb polyfill](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/)

Here's an example of one library that seems to be pretty close to what I'm looking for: [filer](https://github.com/js-platform/filer).

Interested to see what other options people think are good.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/235) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example, include a detailed list of the features you need.

Comment: Deleted my old answer as with the updated details it really doesn't fit instead of barely fitting. I haven't used it yet but [localForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) might be an ideal polyfill - it supports IndexedDB and WebSQL and then falls back to localStorage if needed. It looks quite good but I haven't really used it yet.

Comment: @NickWilde Thanks for the answer and your comment. I didn't get any answers from a couple other questions so that's why I didn't want to ratchet it down too much with specificity. But I think the additional detail is a good thing to have in the question.

Comment: So what's wrong with localForage or Filer?